# How to join a list while preserving previous structure?

Tags: python, list, formatting

I am having trouble joining a pre-split string after modification while preserving the previous structure.

say I have a string like this:

```
string = """

This is a nice piece of string isn't it?
I assume it is so. I have to keep typing
to use up the space. La-di-da-di-da.

This   is    a    spaced   out   sentence

Bonjour.
"""
```

I have to do some tests of that string.. finding specific words and characters within those words etc...and then replace them accordingly. so to accomplish that I had to break it up using

```
string.split()
```

The problem with this is, is that split also gets rid of the \n and extra spaces immediately ruining the integrity of the previous structure

Are there some extra methods in split that will allow me to accomplish this or should I seek an alternative route?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

The `split` method takes an optional argument to specify the delimiter. If you only want to split words using space (`' '`) characters, you can pass that as an argument:

```
>>> string = """
...
... This is a nice piece of string isn't it?
... I assume it is so. I have to keep typing
... to use up the space. La-di-da-di-da.
...
... Bonjour.
... """
>>>
>>> string.split()
['This', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'piece', 'of', 'string', "isn't", 'it?', 'I', 'assume', 'it', 'is', 'so.', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'keep', 'typing', 'to', 'use', 'up', 'the', 'space.', 'La-di-da-di-da.', 'Bonjour.']
>>> string.split(' ')
['\n\nThis', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'piece', 'of', 'string', "isn't", 'it?\nI', 'assume', 'it', 'is', 'so.', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'keep', 'typing\nto', 'use', 'up', 'the', 'space.', 'La-di-da-di-da.\n\nBonjour.\n']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1):

The split method will split your string based on all white-spaces by default. If you want to split the lies separately, you can first split your string with new-lines then split the lines with white-space:

```
>>> [line.split() for line in string.strip().split('\n')]
[['This', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'piece', 'of', 'string', "isn't", 'it?'], ['I', 'assume', 'it', 'is', 'so.', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'keep', 'typing'], ['to', 'use', 'up', 'the', 'space.', 'La-di-da-di-da.'], [], ['Bonjour.']]
```

Answer (score 1):

Just split with a delimiter:

```
>>> string.split(' ')
['\n\nThis', 'is', 'a', 'nice', 'piece', 'of', 'string', "isn't", 'it?\nI', 'assume', 'it', 'is', 'so.', 'I', 'have', 'to', 'keep', 'typing\nto', 'use', 'up', 'the', 'space.', 'La-di-da-di-da.\n\nThis', '', '', 'is', '', '', '', 'a', '', '', '', 'spaced', '', '', 'out', '', '', 'sentence\n\nBonjour.\n']
```

And to get it back:

```
>>> ' '.join(a)
This is a nice piece of string isn't it?
I assume it is so. I have to keep typing
to use up the space. La-di-da-di-da.

This   is    a    spaced   out   sentence

Bonjour.
```

Answer (score 0):

just do `string.split(' ')` (note the space argument to the split method).

this will keep your precious new lines within the strings that go into the resulting array...

Answer (score 0):

You can save the spaces in another list then after modifying the words list you join them together.

```
In [1]: from nltk.tokenize import RegexpTokenizer
In [2]: spacestokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\s+', gaps=False)

In [3]: wordtokenizer = RegexpTokenizer(r'\s+', gaps=True)

In [4]: string = """
   ...: 
   ...: This is a nice piece of string isn't it?
   ...: I assume it is so. I have to keep typing
   ...: to use up the space. La-di-da-di-da.
   ...: 
   ...: This   is    a    spaced   out   sentence
   ...: 
   ...: Bonjour.
   ...: """

In [5]: spaces = spacestokenizer.tokenize(string)

In [6]: words = wordtokenizer.tokenize(string)

In [7]: print ''.join([s+w  for s, w in zip(spaces, words)])


This is a nice piece of string isn't it?
I assume it is so. I have to keep typing
to use up the space. La-di-da-di-da.

This   is    a    spaced   out   sentence

Bonjour.
```